# Oracle Exchange Partition Perfomance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, database-administration, exadata

When I set exchange partition ( auto dop is open), I notice multiblock reading in session events and exchange partition process takes too much time..
But if I set manual dop, job is completed earlier.
i tried
Parallel_min_threshold=0 and 1 as a result of this i couldnt solve problem.

Other paramters: _parallel_cache_policy=Adaptive

_serial_direct_read=AUTO

In addition: query and etl jobs works properly..(Cell smart table scan)  there was only one problem about exchange partition.

Whould you please give your suggestion on this problem.

Solutions and direction

Comment: You may want to consider moving your question to the DBA site. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I changed _serial_direct_read as ALWAYS then problem is solved